# Protecting a new computer nowadays?

Tags: internet, user-education

With so many security threats - how does one protect their PC?

Before it was easy(er?) - have a firewall and an updated anti-virus. But is that enough today?

What type of software would you put on a new, freshly bought computer to keep it safe from most threats?

I would like to note that I'm mostly referring to viruses, key loggers, ransom-ware etc. that you might get from browsing the Internet, not so much software that you install yourself.

As this topic can easily be considered "too broad" or "opinion based" I would like to ask for two things:

1) Make your answer bullet-point organised for each type of software you would install on a new computer to protect it; providing links to favourite/famous software is welcome but not required.

2) To narrow-down the possible threats we try to protect the new PC against - imagine that it's a PC of a clueless user who would browse any web-page, follow any link, use any service, sync smart devices yet will not download any files, install any apps he gets from the Internet, will not proceed to a web-page that's banned by Google/Chrome as it might contain malware and finally user has no Flash Player or Java installed (for Java applets).

Best practices like: not using same password, not letting browsers remember your passwords, not using your PC with admin/root privileges unless you know what you're doing etc. - are not needed since it's a different question all by itself.

Please refrain from comments "there's no 100% security",- that much is known, but the value of this question is to provide a somewhat advanced insight of what it today to have decent security on your personal computer.

Comment: If you believe this question is low quality, please leave a comment as well to help improve the question rather than just down voting.

Comment: Also take a look at https://decentsecurity.com/

Comment: Define "being stupid"; OK, I threw out my firewall, my anti-virus, my traffic logger, I browsed a lot of web-sites, some with JavaScript and other means to infect myself with malware. Then I've synced all that to my off-line hard drive. I'm totally fine, right? :) Try putting that in an answer and look at feedback you'll get.

Comment: Sure, would you like to post it as an answer? If you think that installing any extra software isn't necessary, just write that and explain why. Although I wouldn't completely agree with you, I think that could be a valid answer.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/239950/dont-use-your-antivirus-browser-extensions-they-can-actually-make-you-less-safe/
http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/antivirus-software-1.3668746
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3574724/Is-antivirus-software-putting-risk-Programs-offer-lower-levels-security-browsers.html

Answer (score 5):

The main threat to a computer nowadays is the user. On the software side, most desktop OSes nowadays include a built-in firewall and even antimalware, so extra software would be unnecessary in most cases. An ad blocker would be the only exception and I recommend installing one.

On the other hand despite the evolution of software security, users remained pretty much still and are just as clueless as before. You need to start by forgetting the idea that security is something you can simply buy, install and be done with it. No amount of antimalware will protect you when you want to watch a video, see a fake "video player update" dialog that points to a malicious `.exe`. Even if the antimalware blocks it (which won't yet be the case if the malware is new), you'd probably manually whitelist it because at the end of the day you want to see that new celebrity gossip video so bad, and before you know it, you're already pwned. Combined with other carelessness such as password reuse, no 2FA, no updates on other devices (Android comes to mind, just like routers and most "internet of things" stuff) the attacker can use your computer to reach inside your network and further compromise your other devices.

Here are some things I recommend :

- Keep your OS and software up to date, don't install unnecessary software (less code means less vulnerabilities left to discover and exploit). Uninstall notoriously insecure stuff such as Flash player or the Java web plugin. Resist the temptation to reinstall them, if a site requires them then it is not worthy of your time. If you must have them, configure your browser to "ask to activate" the plugins, and only click to activate them on the site that legitimately requires the plugin.
- Never reuse passwords, use a password manager so you can have secure 30-char passwords and not have to remember them all. Enable two-factor authentication on all your accounts so that even in case of a breach the attackers still won't be able to access your online accounts unless they also breach your 2FA device (usually your phone).
- Understand that as soon as you run some code (a downloaded program, etc), your machine is at the mercy of whoever wrote that code, or whoever managed to intercept your download (always download over HTTPS). It is a good idea to manually verify digital signatures of the files as well.
- A padlock doesn't mean it is safe. A padlock displayed on the page itself is meaningless, as an attacker can insert one himself if the page was served over plain HTTP. A padlock displayed by your browser itself doesn't mean it is completely safe either, it just means your connection between your browser and the server is safe. If the server is malicious or compromised and is serving malware this won't save you. You'll download the malware securely (so nobody else can intercept it and insert his own malware), but at the end of the day it's still malware.
- When someone asks you (on a website, email, phone, etc) to download and run a program, do not do it unless you know who they are, you trust them and you are sure the software is safe and has been downloaded securely (over HTTPS, though HTTP is also safe if you have another means of verifying its authenticity like the file having a digital signature). Some people will call you and pretend they are the Microsoft technical support team - they lie, they are scammers and want you to manually compromise your machine by executing their remote access tool. I would expect many variations of this scam to exist including someone pretending to be your bank and using the urgency of an ongoing money transfer, etc to try and convince you to run their malware.
- Watch out for executable files in general, no matter where they came from. An effective strategy is to send out a file `something tempting.doc.exe` and expect people to get tricked by the `.doc` extension (which is displayed and corresponds to a Word document, which is not totally safe either but much better than the `.exe` hiding behind it) where as the real extension is `.exe` which is definitely dangerous. Windows by default hides the extensions of known files, so you won't actually see the `.exe` and further get tricked by the `.doc` believing it is the real extension. It is not, if it was the real one it wouldn't be displayed at all by that same setting. If you want you can configure your OS to always display all extensions.
- Plan for the worst and have a recovery strategy in place should your computer or phone get compromised. This includes 2FA for online accounts, offline backups against ransomware, and disabling unnecessary devices that can be used to spy on you or gain more private information (for example, cover or unplug your webcam if you don't want [some basement-dwelling psychopath spying on you](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2013/03/rat-breeders-meet-the-men-who-spy-on-women-through-their-webcams/)).

Of course, most people would stop reading after the second line and say "screw this, my `qwerty1234` password is secure enough and no one will bother* hacking me", and this is exactly why I call those people stupid. Don't be like those people. Stay safe.

*attacks are cheap and can be automated and carried out by the same malware running on other people's computers. The "I am not an interesting target" excuse doesn't apply anymore because at worst, even if the attackers don't get anything else (no bank account, personal data, etc), they still have your computer which is a valuable asset as it will be used to carry out other attacks (hosting malware, sending spam, attacking websites, etc), or access to the computer can be resold on the black market to someone else who has an use for it.